# Mongodb: How to Migrate Mongodb database from older version?

Tags: mongodb

I was upgraded my mongodb version from 2.6 to 4.1 and also I take backup my all the database json data to my system and restore it when the updation 
is completed.

But the problem in Robomongo tool it show all the database but inside of that all the collections and schemas are empty.

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [the upgrade path](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-standalone/#upgrade-version-path):

> To upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 4.0, you **must** be running a 3.6-series release.
>
> To upgrade from a version earlier than the 3.6-series, you must successively upgrade major releases until you have upgraded to 3.6-series. For example, if you are running a 3.4-series, you must upgrade first to upgrade first to 3.6 before you can upgrade to 4.0.

Comment: Now am using 2.6v but i want to upgrade to latest 4.What to do for that?.shall i want to upgrade to 3 then 3.2 and so on or any other way to do that?Let me  know the procedure for upgradation? shall i want to take backup of each version data?

Comment: Yes, you should. Full version of the quoted documentation has more links and step-by-step instructions. Please visit the link, read the page behind it, follow relevant links and read related documents.